# How does DPDK prefetch the data in mbuf?

Tags: networking, intel, dpdk, prefetch

[image]

The valid data of the packet is placed in the red part of the mbuf in the figure. When the CPU wants to read the data in the packets, it will access the red part of the mbuf in the figure. So, I want to know how DPDK prefetches the mbuf, it will prefetch the whole mbuf to cache or only prefetch the data part(the red part in the figure).

In addition, it would be better if you could introduce the code of DPDK's prefetching mechanism (prefetch mbuf or RX descriptors) in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK uses architecture-specific prefetch instructions to prefetch data into the cache hierarchy. It also gives a uniform interface(e.g., `rte_prefetch0`) for convenient programming.

You can find definitions of prefetch functions in arch-specific include directories:

- General interface definitions: https://elixir.bootlin.com/dpdk/latest/source/lib/eal/include/generic/rte_prefetch.h
- x86 implementations:
  https://elixir.bootlin.com/dpdk/latest/source/lib/eal/x86/include/rte_prefetch.h
- ARM implementations:
  https://elixir.bootlin.com/dpdk/latest/source/lib/eal/arm/include/rte_prefetch_32.h

---

Prefetch functions accept only one argument: the memory address of prefetched data. Note that the effects of prefetch instructions are also architecture-specific. In x86 (I am more familiar with), prefetch instructions are merely hints, and hardware may ignore them. The amount of data to be prefetched is also uncertain, but it's typically one cacheline (64 Byte) in my experience.

- If DPDK (or DPDK applications) wants to read or write fields of the `rte_mbuf` struct, it usually prefetches the struct directly (`rte_preftch0(mbuf)`).
  Examples: https://elixir.bootlin.com/dpdk/latest/source/drivers/net/i40e/i40e_rxtx.c#L598
- If DPDK (or DPDK applications) want to read or write the packet's content, it usually prefetches the beginning address of the data part (`rte_prefetch0(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf))`). Examples: https://elixir.bootlin.com/dpdk/latest/source/examples/l3fwd/l3fwd_em.h#L134

In practice, DPDK (and DPDK applications) rarely prefetch the whole mbuf or the whole data part. They only prefetch cachelines that are actually accessed, usually the first cacheline of the `rte_mbuf` struct, which contains the most frequently used fields, and the first cache line of the valid data, which usually contains headers of network packets.

Comment: It is a good answer! Actually, what I wonder is that if I change the size of headroom,  will it affect the prefetching of dataroom? So I want to know generally DPDK prefetches by rte_prefetch0(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf))or rte_prefetch0(mbuf). If DPDK prefetches by rte_prefetch0(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf)), I think it would not affect the DPDK prefetching.

Comment: DPDK libs and drivers generally never prefetch data (I search the codebase roughly and find nothing). But they usually prefetch the rte_mbuf struct by `rte_prefetch0(mbuf)`. However, prefetch instructions only prefetch several cache lines, so packet content is unlikely to be prefetched even if headroom is empty. Applications have to prefetch packet contents ( `rte_prefetch0(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf))`) by themselves if they desire.